# Love 2d is not working in my VS Code setup

Tags: visual-studio-code, game-engine, love2d

I have made a new folder to keep my coding files in and folders of Love2D. But since then whenever I press alt+l in my **main.lua** file in vs code, the file doesn't run in love app.

[image: Below is the image of what happens when I press Alt+l in vs code.]

But, when I try to drag and drop the folder of my game onto the love2D shortcut on my desktop, the game runs fine.

Why does this happen?

Here are the settings of my love2d support extension:

[image: Extension Settings]

I have tried reinstalling love, also tried to reinstall the extension, and installing any previous version of love.

I tried to open the project directly as a project too.
[image: as above]

Pls, can someone help me at the earliest?

Comment: I am using not VS or LÖVE on MS-Windows. But i can imagine that the LÖVE Path is not working because of the space in ```\Program Files\``` ? I would try and suggest a test folder without space(s) like: ```C:\love\love.exe```

Answer (score 1):

You provided `.` as the src directory in the support extension, which probably tries to launch `PIYUSH_LOVE2D` as the game (which does not contain a `main.lua`).

Either open the game directory directly as a project in VS Code or enter the path of the game in `Src Dir`.

**EDIT**: Alt+L while the `main.lua` is open works and uses the dir containing the main as the root. The correct path is only required if the `main.lua` is not open.

Comment: I tried opening the folder directly as a project but it didn't work. Take a look in the question again I have appended the results.

Comment: Ok, I installed both VS and love2d extension. Alt+L while in the `main.lua` should work even if it is not in the projects root dir. I edited my answer. Just to clarify, what happens if you press Alt+L? Does an error msg pop up?

Answer (score 0):

I found something that can help you on the LÖVE 2D website. Take a look:

> “Remember to drag the folder containing main.lua, and not main.lua itself”

I don't know much about VS Code but I think to solve your problem you could configure it to run the **game folder** in LOVE, instead of its main.

Comment: Yes, it works when I drag and drop the folder itself on love2d. But doesn't run with  with Alt+L directly

Answer (score 0):

I'm late to answering this but I hope it helps someone. It looks like you have Live Server extension installed, I believe that also has a key combo of ALT+L, which interferes with the Love2D extension.

Try removing Live Server, or change the key combo to something other than ALT+L for either of the extensions.